# Gremlin What is the difference between transform and sideEffect

Tags: gremlin

total n00b here when it comes to Gremlin, but would someone mind telling me the difference between a "transform" and "sideEffect"?  I read the Gremlin Docs and both seem to "at times" take inputs, massage the data, and produce outputs.

I thought I was on to something when it looked like "transforms" were mostly "getters", but then why would it be called "transform"?  And then I saw that they put functions under transform that did much more than just get data.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `transform` behaves as a map function, where the value in the Gremlin Pipeline is literally tranformed to a different value:

```
gremlin> g.V.transform{it.name}
==>marko
==>vadas
==>lop
==>josh
==>ripple
==>peter
```

Note that in the example above, we've gone from a `Vertex` before the `transform` step to the string value of the `name` property on that `Vertex`.  Now watch what happens with `sideEffect`:

```
gremlin> g.V.sideEffect{it.name}
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
```

The `Vertex` passes through `sideEffect` unchanged (i.e. it exits the `sideEffect` as a `Vertex`, just as it went in).  The point of a `sideEffect` is that you can do something at that step of the pipeline that does "something" unrelated to the processing of the pipeline itself.  In other words, the return value of the `sideEffect` closure is basically ignored.

Comment: Stephen, that is an excellent answer.  I especially appreciate the way you explained what is happening during the sideEffect.  Many thanks.

Comment: How does one have the pipeline return a single object containing the end vertex and any side effects accumulated earlier?

Comment: by "end vertex", do you mean the last one to pass through pipe?  and by a "single object" do you mean like a List like: `[lastVertex, sideEffect]`?

Comment: How to append the value of sideEffect to the output ? @stephenmallette

Comment: judging from the syntax this is a TinkerPop 2.x question, but conceptually the answer is largely the same in 3.x iirc - you can `cap()` out side effects http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#cap-step